# PHP - login into https website and get a html file within that session

Tags: php, ssl, https, file-get-contents, fsockopen

I have a parser for a html page which return a dynamic ics file to use with google calendar. It works fine with the simple_html_dom library and with the file_get_contents while using a local html file for test.

however the page I need to parse is on a TLS server, behind a login page (https).
to access my page I need to login first on a different page and keep the connection alive to parse the second page.

I managed to create a link (modifying the login form from POST to GET) which allow me to log straight in without need for the form (I know that this makes the TLS connection useless for his purpose). I can still use the POST with the login details if I can make this work.

```
https://selfservice.host.domain.lol/portal?LOGON_LOCALE_POLICY=&StartIndex=0&authenticateWithSecurityQuestion=false&authenticateWithHRMSNewUserSetup=false&username=<username>&password=<stocazzo>
```

I tried with file_get_conents but when I require the second page the session for the auth is already closed.
I tried as well with fsockopen on tls://selfservice.host.domain.lol on 443 and than request with both POST or GET string taken from the browser BUT the connection just goes in time out.

I'm not a pro user and the last time I've been playing with php and programming the php5 was not even in our dreams.

Any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems legit, Stocazzo is the main problem.